# Zoom map after Cluster click

Tags: android, google-maps, zooming

I am trying to implement zoom after `onClusterClick` but i am using this library [Link](https://github.com/sharewire/google-maps-clustering) and i do not how to do it. In Google library

```
 @Override
 public boolean onClusterClick(final Cluster<MyItem> cluster) {
   map.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(
   cluster.getPosition(), (float) Math.floor(map
   .getCameraPosition().zoom + 1)), 300,null);
                return true;`
```

but i do not have `getPosition()`. I have only `getLatitude()` and `getLongitude`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
map.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(new LatLng(getLatitude(), getLongitude()), MY_ZOOM)
```

Or this option

```
LatLngBounds.Builder builder = LatLngBounds.builder();
for (SampleClusterItem item : cluster.getItems()) {
    builder.include(new LatLng(item.getLatitude(), item.getLongitude()));
}
final LatLngBounds bounds = builder.build();

try {
    mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngBounds(bounds, PADDING));
} catch (Exception e) {
    Log.e("TAG_SNAP", "onClusterClick: " + e.getMessage());
}
```